# Proof Explanation: If a function is increasing and bounded above, then the left sided limit exists at every point.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was hoping someone could explain the following proof:

> If a function is monotone increasing and bounded above, then $\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)$ exists at every point $a$.

**Proof.** The sequence $\left\{a-\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ being increasing, the sequence $f\left(\left\{a-\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right)$ is increasing, too. But since the last sequence is also bounded, hence it is convergent. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\left\{a-\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right)=g$. It remains for us to prove that the conditions $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=a$ and $x_{n}<a$ imply the equation 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_{n})=g.
$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then there is an $m$ such that $g-f\left(\left\{a-\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)<\varepsilon$. To this $m$ we choose a number $k$ such that the inequality $n>k$ implies $a-\frac{1}{m}<x_{n}$. Hence $f\left(\left\{a-\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)<f(x_{n}),$ whence
$$
g-f(x_{n})<g-f\left(\left\{a-\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)<\varepsilon.
$$
Moreover, to each $n$ there exists $r_{n}$ such that $x_{n}<a-\frac{1}{r_n}$. Hence
$$
f(x_{n})<f\left(\left\{a-\frac{1}{r_{n}}\right\}\right)\le{g},\qquad\text{i.e.}\qquad g-f(x_{n})>0.
$$
Hence we conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_{n})=g$.

---

In particular, what purpose does $r_{n}$ serve?

Comment: Do you expect that someone will explain you every step of the proof?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos "In particular, what pupose does $r_{n}$ serve?"

Comment: You don't need the bounded above thing as it is redundant. If $x\to a^{-} $ then by increasing nature of $f$ we automatically have $f(x) \leq f(a) $.

Comment: “I was hoping someone could explain the following proof:”

Comment: And there is no need of sequences, just show that desired limit is supremum of the set $\{f(x) \mid x\leq a\} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof proceeds in two steps

1. $g-f(x_n)<\epsilon$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon>0$.
2. $0\le g-f(x_n)$.

Combining these two steps yields $0 \le g-f(x_n)<\epsilon$ and letting $\epsilon\to 0$ yields the result. Hence, $r_n$ is needed to establish the second step. In particular $x_n<a$ implies that there exists an integer - denoted by $r_n$ - such that still $x_n+\frac1{r_n}<a$. By strict monotonicity of $f$, this in turn implies that $f(x_n)<f(a-1/r_n)$. Now, by the very first part of the proof, this implies that $f(a-1/r_n)\le g$ which concludes the second step.